# Setting default browser programmatically

Tags: android, mdm, samsung-knox

As I'm creating an Android MDM application, I want to use my policies to establish the default browser. Can my default browser be set programmatically? Thus, the default browser will be established automatically without user input if the admin activates the policy, and the user not allowed change the default browser manually.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.